# Guardar articulos/post con formato e imagenes

Tags: php, mysql, web

he buscado en algunos cursos o en google pero no he tenido éxito o de pronto me he comido la cabeza solo.
Si tengo una página tipo blog, artículos de información con texto bonito con un tipo de letra, en cursiva y con estilos de nose que y algunas imagenes dentro.
¿Como puedo guardar todo ese formato del artículo? 
¿Estoy intentando con php y mysql, hay algún tipo de dato o estrategia a seguir en éste caso? No quiero hacerlo con WordPress.

Comment: Debes de utilizar para ello las hojas de estilo o css. Te paso un enlace al respecto. CSS Tutorial: [https://www.w3schools.com/css/](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Comment: Gracias por responder M. Galardi pero no es lo que busco. De pronto no me expliqué bien. Necesito obtener el texto enriquecido o nose cual será el nombre, más las imagenes existentes dentro del artículo.

Comment: Hola, lo que estas buscando es [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/), hechale un vistazo, este te permite guardar texto en formato html, con imágenes, links, texto con formato, etc. perfecto para blogs.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que preguntas es sencillo. Debes usar MySQL para guardar lo que seria los articulos en una base de datos. No te recomiendo que guardes imagenes en una base de datos, ya que son muy pesados y puede bajar significativamente el rendimiento.

Entonces, si quieres guardar un articulo hay varios aspectos a tomar en cuenta;

1. Cada articulo es unico, asi que cada articulo debe tener una id diferente
2. Cada articulo tiene titulo y un contenido, asi que debes crear una columna que se llame titulo y contenido
3. Si agregaras imagenes, recomiendo que las imagenes las guardes en una carpeta aparte, entonces lo que gaurdarias en la base de datos, seria su nombre y extension y tu programarias la direccion con PHP.

Realmente te ayudaria a mostrarte un codigo PHP, pero lo que pides es muy extenso, te recomiendo que veas unos tutoriales simples de PHP, tutoriales que te enseñen como trabajar archivos en PHP, ya que asi puedes evitar una SQL inyeccion o subida de archivos no deseado